# Javascript for conditional URL append or redirect based on window.location.href

Tags: javascript, url, conditional-statements, append, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a bookmarklet that when clicked will check the URL of the current tab/window to see if it contains 'char1' and/or 'char2' (a given character). If both chars are present it redirects to another URL, for the other two it will append the current URL respectively.

I believe there must be a more elegant way of stating this than the following (which has so far worked perfectly for me) but I don't have great knowledge of Javascript. My (unwieldy & repetitive) working code (apologies):

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('char1') != -1 &&
    window.location.href.indexOf('char2') != -1)
{
    window.location="https://website.com/";
}
else if (window.location.href.indexOf('char1') != -1)
{
    window.location.assign(window.location.href += 'append1');
}
else if (window.location.href.indexOf('char2') != -1)
{
    window.location.assign(window.location.href += 'append2');
}
```

Does exactly what I need it to but, well... not very graceful to say the least.

Is there a simpler way to do this, perhaps with vars or a pseudo-object? Or better code?

Comment: Thanks for the format roosteronacid, it was a bit cruel of me leaving the code in bookmarklet form.

I'm very grateful to those who contributed time & code. I hadn't expected such a wealth of input so quickly.

-Wintermute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (sort-of) refactoring of dthorpe's suggestion:

```
var hasC1  = window.location.href.indexOf('char1')!=-1
var hasC2  = window.location.href.indexOf('char2')!=-1
var newLoc = hasC1 
               ? hasC2 ? "https://website.com/" : window.location.href+'append1'
               : hasC2 ? window.location.href+'append1' : '';

if (newLoc)
    window.location = newLoc;
```

Calling `assign` is the same as assigning a value to `window.location`, you were doing both with the addition assignment `+=` operator in the method anyway:

```
window.location.assign(window.location.href+='append2')
```

This would actually assign "append2" to the end of `window.location.href` before calling the assign method, making it redundant.

You could also reduce DOM lookups by setting `window.location` to a var.

Comment: "Calling assign is the same as assigning a value to window.location..."  

That's what I thought, but the script kept returning the appended URL to the document window instead of the address bar, and the address bar contained the javascript. History-1 returned to the former page with the appended URL in the address bar. So I wrapped it in the assign function to try and force it to use the result. It worked, but was redundant. 

Incidentally, your code is doing the same thing: returning the appended URL to the doc win, not the address bar.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help out. I tried to make some vars myself but it was resolving; I'm not sure what I did wrong but I was highly distracted by my friends' kids who were taking my house to pieces at the time haha...  I appreciate your input.

Comment: @Wintermute: np.  That does seem like an odd issue you're having.  You could change `window.location = newLoc` for `window.location.assign(newLoc)` but as I mentioned before, they are near enough the same thing.

Comment: I think it may be something to do with Javascipt in Firefox; it appears to be interpreting the result as a string literal and loading it into the browser window...? <code>.assign(newLoc)</code> returns as expected & working beautifully now. Also with a new var: <code>loc = window.location</code>. It's now just <code>loc.property</code> or <code>loc.function</code>. Thanks again Andy E's Head.

Answer (score 3):

The only reduction I can see is to pull out the redundant indexof calls into vars and then test the vars.  It's not going to make any appreciable difference in performance though.

```
var hasChar1 = window.location.href.indexOf('char1') != -1;
var hasChar2 = window.location.href.indexOf('char2') != -1;
if (hasChar1)
{
   if (hasChar2)
   {
      window.location="https://website.com/";
   }
   else
   {
      window.location.assign(window.location.href+='append1');
   }
} 
else if (hasChar2)
{
    window.location.assign(window.location.href+='append2');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm grateful for your input. This is a much better structured 'if' and resolves a little more logically than mine. I'm curious to know if there was a reason why you used the same assign(loc.href+=) as me... it's redundant, but the only way I could force the result onto the location.href as opposed to returning a string to the main document window.

Comment: This is working very well for me. I have gone further and, as Andy E suggested, added a new var: loc = window.location. It's now just loc.property or loc.function.

Comment: I didn't look closely at the window.location assignments.  

Say hello to Neuromancer for me.  ;>

Comment: He runs with loa now, but I'll try to get his Hash

Comment: Easy to understand, and got it to work on Firefox! I just did `if (hasChar1) { window.location="https://website.com"; }`

Answer (score 2):

Kind of extendable code. Am i crazy?

```
var loc = window.location.href;
var arr = [{
  url: "https://website.com/",
  chars: ["char1", "char2"]
}, {
  url: loc + "append1",
  chars: ["char1"]
}, {
  url: loc + "append2",
  chars: ["char2"]
}];

function containsChars(str, chars)
{
  var contains = true;
  for(index in chars) {
    if(str.indexOf(chars[index]) == -1) {
      contains = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return contains;
}

for(index in arr) {
 var item = arr[index];
 if(containsChars(loc, item.chars)) {
    window.location.href = item.url;
    break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Crazy? No, but probably used to frying much bigger fish :) This would be great if implementing within a site\domain because it is much more flexible & extensible, from what I can see. I imagine it would be particularly useful for checking query strings and\or searches, you could redirect users to FAQ or special public notices relating to their browsing or site search. Nice one, but for my needs it's like killing a mosquito with a nuke LOL.

Answer (score 0):

var location =window.location.href

```
if (location.indexOf('char1')!=-1 &&  location.indexOf('char2')!=-1)
{window.location="https://website.com/";} 
else if (location.href.indexOf('char1')!=-1) {window.location.assign(location+='append1');}
else if (location.indexOf('char2')!=-1) {window.location.assign(location+='append2');}
```

Comment: Nice & succinct, just how I like it. Further reduction in code from using 2 vars: `loc=window.location` & `url=loc.href`. This also runs foul of the `location=""` returning to the doc window as a string instead of the address. `loc.assign()` (with the above vars) corrects this. I think it's because appending a string to the location converts it to a string lit, and that in turn is treated as document content therefore it goes to the doc window. Thanks for your input!